# Google Analytics not tracking data

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

We have a total of six websites. Three for two countries consisting of (mobile, desktop and store). Individual tracking code was created for each but after speaking to our developers they put a different code across each site so that we could combine the total set of data of each site in one report.

We have been navigating the sites and placing test orders but nothing is being picked up in GA Dashboard. Not in Real Time either.

Do we need to add each unique tracking code to each site? If So how can these be combined to make one complete report.

Each site has it's own unique code (example)

```
 /* Google Universal Analytics */

              (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)    {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
              m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
              })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

              ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-01', 'auto');
              ga('require', 'ecommerce');
              ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

But our devs have added the same code to all sites. Example

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-12', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Partial answer here, as you may need to provide more code samples of your ecommerce implementation if want help debugging that.]

With the same tracking code across all sites, you effectively have a rollup property. But you will need to add specific filters so that can differentiate the traffic from one site to the other, so add a hostname prepend filter at least so that you see which site traffic is from.

If you want to see site specific data with the rollup property, you will need to create individual views for each site, in addition to your best practice views (eg. Test and Raw). Each site-specific view should have an include filter that only shows permits data for that specific site.

If you want to include an individual property for each site, then you will need to give that tracking object a specific name ( Google 'named trackers'), but at least you wouldn't need to create separate views in your rollup property.

To check your hits, use a tool like GA Debugger for Chrome, or check your developer's network tab for the GA requests.